# Can I send a message to a customer on facebook messenger once he completes an order?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger-bot

I saw the following screenshot on [this page](https://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/how-to-use-facebook-messenger-for-your-business/).

[image]

From the look of it, it sent order details to a customer upon completion of her order to her facebook messenger. I can't find any of the [facebook messenger plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/) capable of doing this. Can you please help me find out how did they actually did it? I want to replicate it for my site. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Send to messenger plugin and checkbox plugin could be used to create this type of functionality.